# error in process sentinel: Invalid file-name during replacing words

Tags: replace, flymake

I am getting following error `error in process sentinel: Invalid file-name` due to generated `_flymake.py` files, when I am following [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/271136/2402577) for the *recursively find and replace in text files not already open*. Please note that, files (`*flymake.py`) are generated when `find-name-dired` is used, I think right after `Q` is pressed for `Query-Replace in Files`.

Is there any way to prevent this error from happening? Could I ignore files ending with `_flymake.py` during replacement?

Comment: You probably need to turn off [flymake-mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Flymake.html). Also, you are in charge of all the files that are selected for replacement: just mark the ones you want and leave the others unmarked, instead of pressing `t` to toggle them all on.

Comment: They are hunderds of files show up, its hard to find which ends with `_flymake.py` on each replacement. Is it possible to turn-off before replacement and turn-on again after it? Please note that `elpy-flymake-python-init`  seems enables.

Comment: I have added `(setq flymake-start-on-flymake-mode nil)` seems like working for now